# Saving javafx WritableImage with ImageIO does not work

Tags: java, javafx, canvas, snapshot, javax.imageio

I am creating a tool able to create masks for images (dataset preparation for neural network learning). The user is supposed to draw with the cursor on a canvas, which is nested in an anchor pane, which has an image as its background. The canvas has opacity set to 0.5.

This is a maven-built project on Intellij Idea.

I think it is worth mentioning that the Canvas object does not store information about the image, it is set to black and by drawing, user creates on it white circles.

I am stuck at saving the image to file. I've read many questions on SO and none of them worked for me.

Screenshot from my app:
[image: Screenshot of my app]

Written image (it should be black background with this white V-like mark):

[image: Screenshot of rendered image]

Here is the code for onClick listener for the button (saving the file). I have set color of the snapshot as transparent and desaturated the image to grayscale.

```
@FXML
    public void onClickButton(ActionEvent evt) throws IOException {

        SnapshotParameters sp = new SnapshotParameters();
        sp.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        WritableImage image = user_mask_canvas.snapshot(sp, null);

        //desaturafion to get grayscale image
        ImageView desaturated = new ImageView(image);
        ColorAdjust desaturate = new ColorAdjust();
        desaturate.setSaturation(-1);
        desaturated.setEffect(desaturate);

        BufferedImage i =SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(desaturated.getImage(), null);


        File file = new File("image.bmp");
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            ImageIO.write(i, "bmp", file);
            System.out.println("written");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Here is the full code.

Main:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package sample;

import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.effect.ColorAdjust;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button button;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane image_placeholder;

    @FXML
    private Canvas user_mask_canvas;
    //this is supposed to be in the anchor pane

    private String imgRef;

    final WritableImage wb = new WritableImage(96,96);


    @FXML
    public void onClickButton(ActionEvent evt) throws IOException {

        SnapshotParameters sp = new SnapshotParameters();
        sp.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        WritableImage image = user_mask_canvas.snapshot(sp, null);

        //desaturafion to get grayscale image
        ImageView desaturated = new ImageView(image);
        ColorAdjust desaturate = new ColorAdjust();
        desaturate.setSaturation(-1);
        desaturated.setEffect(desaturate);

        BufferedImage i =SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(desaturated.getImage(), null);


        File file = new File("image.bmp");
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            ImageIO.write(i, "bmp", file);
            System.out.println("written");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        WritableImage image = new WritableImage(96,96);
        try {
            SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/1.tif")), image);
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BackgroundImage myBI= new BackgroundImage(image,
                BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT,
                BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);
        image_placeholder.setBackground(new Background(myBI));

        final GraphicsContext graphicsContext = user_mask_canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        graphicsContext.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        graphicsContext.fillRect(0, 0, user_mask_canvas.getWidth(), user_mask_canvas.getHeight());
        graphicsContext.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        graphicsContext.setStroke(Color.WHITE);

        user_mask_canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
                new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        //graphicsContext.beginPath();
                        graphicsContext.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        graphicsContext.stroke();

                    }
                });

        user_mask_canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED,
                new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        graphicsContext.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        graphicsContext.stroke();
                        graphicsContext.fillOval(event.getX(), event.getY(), 8, 8);
                        //graphicsContext.closePath();
                        //graphicsContext.beginPath();
                        graphicsContext.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    }
                });

        user_mask_canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED,
                new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        graphicsContext.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        graphicsContext.stroke();
                        //graphicsContext.closePath();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

sample.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <center>
        <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <Canvas height="200.0" width="200.0" />
                <AnchorPane fx:id="image_placeholder" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="96.0">
               <children>
                        <Canvas fx:id="user_mask_canvas" height="96.0" opacity="0.5" width="96.0" />
               </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            <Button fx:id="button" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClickButton" text="Button" />
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: From the code you posted: `SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/1.tif")), image);` Which JDK version are you using? "tif" images may not be supported.

Comment: I am using JDK8. Image '1.tif' is the purple-ish image shown on the first screenshot. It loads normally.

Comment: It loads normally as background to `AnchorPane`. I want to mention that `Canvas` does not store information about '1.tif' image. It is set to black and the user writes it with white circles. The image is been written in 'bmp' format.

Comment: This line of your code: `ImageIO.write(i, "bmp", file);` returns a `boolean` indicating whether the operation succeeded or not. You will find that it returns `false`. In other words, the `BufferedImage` you have created cannot be saved in a file using BMP format.

Comment: It didn't let me to save to `bmp`, but saved to `tif` with no problem... im confused. Thanks for help.